# clustering disk pages In the most I/O efficient manner

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

Let's suppose there're consecutive 5 disk pages (each disk page size = 8KB).

```
P0 P1 P2 P3 P4
```

Among those 5 pages, we need to read P0, P1 and P3. There are three ways to load those pages:

```
[1] Issue three, 8KB I/O requests for P0, P1 and P3. 
[2] Issue one 16KB (for P0 and P1) and one 8KB I/O request (for P3)
[3] Issue one 32KB (for P0, P1, P2, and P3) I/O request and then discard P2 once the request is done.
```

Of course, different I/O requests have different read costs. For example, let's suppose 8KB, 16KB and 32KB I/O requests would be taken like 1ms, 3ms, and 10ms (just artificial numbers...) Then we can calculate the total required I/O time for each method.

```
[1] 3 * 1ms = 3ms
[2] 1 * 1ms + 1 * 3 ms = 4 ms
[3] 1 * 10ms = 10ms
```

In this example, as you can see, using the first method (i.e., issuing three 8KB I/Os) is the most cost effective.

Question: When we know costs of different I/O requests, is there any decent algorithm to cluster pages so that we can issue I/Os in the most cost effective way? This looks like a traditional clustering algorithm, but I can't think of the one...

Comment: Offtopic. This isn't programming, this is more theory. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just a very vague guess: This *could* also be related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem (in the simplest form, it does not take the request times into account, but maybe there is some approximation algorithm that can be adapted)